# Using a Barbie type as a field in another Barbie type with Barbies-TH

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, template-haskell, higher-kinded-types

I'd like to use [Barbies-TH](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/barbies-th) to create two Barbie records, where one is used as a field type in the other:

```
data Player = MkPlayer
  { playerLeft, playerRight, playerShoot, playerStart :: Bool
  } 

data Inputs = MkInputs
  { player1, player2 :: Player
  , dips :: BitVector 8
  , coin :: Bool
  }
```

I can wrap the first one in `declareBareB` just fine:

```
import Barbies
import Barbies.Bare
import Barbies.TH

declareBareB [d|
  data Player = MkPlayer
    { playerLeft, playerRight, playerShoot, playerStart :: Bool
    } |]
```

However, because now the kind of `Player` is `Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Type`, I can't use it inside a `declareBareB` for `Inputs`, where the whole point is to pretend that there's no wrapper functor:

```
declareBareB [d|
  data Inputs = MkInputs
    { player1, player2 :: Player
    , dips :: BitVector 8
    , coin :: Bool
    } |]
```

This gives the, quite unsurprising, type error:

```
src/Hardware/SpaceInvaders/Input.hs:11:1: error:

     • Expecting two more arguments to ‘Player’
       Expected a type, but
       ‘Player’ has kind
       ‘Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Type’
     • In the third argument of ‘Wear’, namely ‘Player’
       In the type ‘(Wear sw_aRck h_aRcl Player)’
       In the definition of data constructor ‘MkInputs’
    |
 11 | declareBareB [d|
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

What I'd like is to somehow propagate the clothes of `Inputs` to the `Player`, so that the type coming out of Barbies-TH would be

```
data Inputs cover f = MkInputs
    { player1, player2 :: Player cover f
    , dips :: Wear cover f (BitVector 8)
    , coin :: Wear cover f Bool
    }
```

(and NOT `player1, player2 :: Wear cover f (Player Bare Identity)`)

Comment: I expect there’s no way to do this with the basic Template Haskell API; you can pass multiple declarations in the `[d| … |]` quote, but it looks like the library just processes them all separately. Can you instead use the `Generic`/`DeriveAnyClass` API, writing the wrappers out explicitly but deriving all the other stuff? Or inline `Player` into `Inputs` (as 4 fields or 1 4-tuple) if you don’t need it to be separate.

Comment: @JonPurdy sure I could always just inline `Player`, but I'd rather not...